# Reading browser's Accept header in Javascript

Tags: javascript, http, http-accept-header

While it's possible to get the browser's User-Agent in Javascript via `navigator.userAgent`, is it likewise possible to get the browser's `Accept` header without performing a HTTP request?

Comment: Take a look at this question, it might suite your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript

Comment: This is not really about parsing an incoming response. I'm trying to see if it's possible to access it as a *property of the browser* per the `navigator.userAgent` example. On the server-side, it would come through as the *request* header `HTTP_ACCEPT`. It's not looking good (as in possible) anyways and doesn't fit the original application I was going to use it for so this may be a closed door at this point.

Comment: Also looking for this information - as new banking 3dSecure  (2021) is requesting we send BrowserInfo (incl. acceptHeader info).

I see this is 4 years+ old - but if anyone stumbles across this, I'd love to hear if there is a simple way to access it as OP states - i.e similar to accessing 'navigator.userAgent'

Thanks

Comment: @DavidPears, have you found a solution for this? I have the same issue because of 3dSecure version 2.0 as well.

Comment: Anyone every figure this out? I want to get the browers default value for its `Accept` header from JavaScript.  I need to make an AJAX fetch request using the exact `Accept` header that the browser usually sends by default when it requests a webpage.